# Trying to add new key and value to the mysql result object but not working so my question is to how to add new key value and send it to the client

Tags: mysql, node.js, api, express, rest

I am trying to add new key value to the mysql result object but its now working how to fix it ?

i am trying to fetch all the post from post database and also check if the post is like or not from post_likes table and if it is liked add {isLike:true} otherwise false in the post request object

```
const fetchPost = (req, res, next) => {
  const sql = "SELECT account.name,account.username,post.content,post.likes, post.visibility,post.date,post.time, post.profile, post.id FROM post INNER JOIN account ON account.uid = post.user_id WHERE post.visibility = 'Friends' OR post.visibility = 'Public'";
  // const sql = "SELECT * FROM post";
  connectDB.query(sql, (err, post_result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return next(createCustomError(err, 400));
    }
    const get_uid_query = `SELECT id FROM account where uid = '${req.user['uid']}'`;

    // get the id of user by uid
    connectDB.query(get_uid_query, (err, user_id_result) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      const id = (user_id_result[0]['id']);

      for (let i = 0; i < post_result.length; i++) {
        const sql = `SELECT user_id, post_id FROM post_likes WHERE post_id = ${post_result[i]['id']} AND user_id = ${id}`;
        connectDB.query(sql, (err, result) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          else if (result.length > 0) {
            post_result[i]['isliked'] = true;

          } else {
            post_result[i]['isLiked'] = false;  
          }
        })
      }
      res.status(200).json(post_result); // isLiked value not sending with the response how to fix it 
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: actually i am trying to access all the post from the database and in the result object i will try to add isLike = ture or false bassed on post_likes table and check if the post is liked or not

Answer (score 0):

You are needlessly running multiple queries when you can easily get the information with just one.

I am not very familiar with node.js, so this may have errors in it:

```
const fetchPost = (req, res, next) => {
    const sql = `
        SELECT
            a.name, a.username, p.content, p.likes, p.visibility, p.date, p.time, p.profile, p.id,
            EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM post_likes pl WHERE p.id = pl.post_id AND pl.user_id = (SELECT id FROM account WHERE uid = ?)) AS isLiked
        FROM post p
        INNER JOIN account a ON a.uid = p.user_id
        WHERE p.visibility = 'Friends' OR p.visibility = 'Public'
    `;
    
    connectDB.query(sql, [req.user['uid']], (err, post_result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return next(createCustomError(err, 400));
        }

        res.status(200).json(post_result);

    })
}
```